# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads

Tags: c++, linux, linker, pthreads, fedora

I'm compiling NVIDIA Caffe tool on a Fedora 22 and I having problems to find `lpthread` library:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_d410e/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_d410e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_d410e -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: En la función `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): referencia a `pthread_create' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d410e.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_d410e' failed
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_d410e/fast' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_d410e] Error 1
gmake: *** [cmTC_d410e/fast] Error 2

File /home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_e693b/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_e693b
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_e693b -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld outputs 1
CMakeFiles/cmTC_e693b.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_e693b' failed
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_e693b/fast' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_e693b] Error 1
gmake: *** [cmTC_e693b/fast] Error 2
```

It seems that it doesn't find pthreads lib (`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads`), but running command `find / name "*pthread*"` it outputs this:

```
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so
/usr/lib64/libpthread.a
/usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.21.so
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

But there is something strange with this, becaue CMakeOutut.log has this:
Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthread passed with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_705ba/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_705ba
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_705ba -rdynamic -lpthread 
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/Sources/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

It has this line using `lpthread`:

```
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_705ba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_705ba -rdynamic -lpthread
```

And this is CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

# ---[ Caffe project
project(Caffe C CXX)

# ---[ Caffe version
set(CAFFE_TARGET_VERSION "0.14.5")
set(CAFFE_TARGET_SOVERSION "0.14")
add_definitions(-DCAFFE_VERSION=${CAFFE_TARGET_VERSION})

# ---[ Using cmake scripts and modules
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules)

include(ExternalProject)

include(cmake/Utils.cmake)
include(cmake/Targets.cmake)
include(cmake/Misc.cmake)
include(cmake/Summary.cmake)
include(cmake/ConfigGen.cmake)

# ---[ Options
caffe_option(CPU_ONLY  "Build Caffe without CUDA support" OFF) # TODO: rename to USE_CUDA
caffe_option(USE_CUDNN "Build Caffe with cuDNN library support" ON IF NOT CPU_ONLY)
caffe_option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" ON)
caffe_option(BUILD_python "Build Python wrapper" ON)
set(python_version "2" CACHE STRING "Specify which Python version to use")
caffe_option(BUILD_matlab "Build Matlab wrapper" OFF IF UNIX OR APPLE)
caffe_option(BUILD_docs   "Build documentation" ON IF UNIX OR APPLE)
caffe_option(BUILD_python_layer "Build the Caffe Python layer" ON)
caffe_option(USE_OPENCV "Build with OpenCV support" ON)
caffe_option(USE_LEVELDB "Build with levelDB" ON)
caffe_option(USE_LMDB "Build with lmdb" ON)
caffe_option(ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK "Allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)" OFF)

# ---[ Dependencies
include(cmake/Dependencies.cmake)

# ---[ Flags
if(UNIX OR APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wall")
endif()

if(USE_libstdcpp)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++")
  message("-- Warning: forcing libstdc++ (controlled by USE_libstdcpp option in cmake)")
endif()

add_definitions(-DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE)

# ---[ Warnings
caffe_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized)

# ---[ Config generation
configure_file(cmake/Templates/caffe_config.h.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/caffe_config.h")

# ---[ Includes
set(Caffe_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(THIRDPARTY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty)
include_directories(${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ${THIRDPARTY_DIR})
include_directories(BEFORE src) # This is needed for gtest.

# ---[ Subdirectories
add_subdirectory(src/gtest)
add_subdirectory(src/caffe)
add_subdirectory(tools)
add_subdirectory(examples)
add_subdirectory(python)
add_subdirectory(matlab)
add_subdirectory(docs)

# ---[ Linter target
add_custom_target(lint COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/lint.cmake)

# ---[ pytest target
add_custom_target(pytest COMMAND python${python_version} -m unittest discover -s caffe/test WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/python )
add_dependencies(pytest pycaffe)

# ---[ Configuration summary
caffe_print_configuration_summary()

# ---[ Export configs generation
caffe_generate_export_configs()
```

What do I have to install? Does libphreads exist or I have to use libphread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You should use `-lpthread` instead of `-lpthreads`.

Alternatively you can just use `-pthread`, that also works.

Comment: Maybe Caffe has a typo. I'm only running `cmake ..`

Comment: Then you should share your `cmake` config file. Somewhere therein there will be an incorrect definition of the pthread switch value

Comment: It'll most likely be called `CMakeLists` or `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: I have updated my question with the contents of CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I just did a search on `pthreads` in the nvidia/caffe project and nothing was found in the current commit. Sounds like a reclone would fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when I follow the caffe doc on a new Ubuntu, and after some Google with `caffe collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`, I find I was lack of some packages, not typo:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libboost-all-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev protobuf-compiler libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip gfortran
```

For more detailed info, ref [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2348).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by googletest, and just set the following line of CMakeList.txt of googletest:

```
option(gtest_disable_pthreads "Disable uses of pthreads in gtest." ON)
```

by the flags on.

The reason is:

We must check for the threads library under a number of different
names; the ordering is very important because some systems
(e.g. DEC) have both `-lpthread` and `-lpthreads`, where one of the
libraries is broken (non-POSIX).