# compiling SCIP: '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads'

Tags: cmake, compilation, ld, scip

I give up.

I am trying to compile SCIP from the source out of tarball [scipoptsuite-7.0.3.tgz](https://scipopt.org/index.php#download). Followed the [Install instruction](https://scipopt.org/doc/html/md_INSTALL.php), but cmake fails.

CMakeError.log says: **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads**. I searched and found this thread form 5½ years ago: [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967086/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpthreads). The top comment says, that it is a typo, it should be **lpthread** instead of **lpthreads** but I did not write the code and I have to think, that that is not the case. Also I could not find where the flag -lpthreads was passed either. The other comments could not solve my problem either.

Does someone have an idea?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on amd64.

`Here is a pastebin of the full output from cmake:` [cmake_output](https://pastebin.com/UYEKXiB1)

`Here is a pastebin of the full CMakeError.log:` [CMakeError](https://pastebin.com/UnweQ6Pc)

I am grateful for all and any help.

Comment: That's `-pthread`

Comment: The **actual error** (in the CMake output) is `Could NOT find Readline (missing: Readline_INCLUDE_DIR Readline_LIBRARY)`. pthreads is absolutely unrelated. The [documentation](https://scipopt.org/doc/html/md_INSTALL.php) notes that readline is required and tells that is is provided by `libreadline-dev` package.

Comment: Thank you, I believe you were right, the problem was with the readline library.